# convert nested structure to flat key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, breadcrumbs

I have nested structure very similar to folder structure, like:

```
Array
(
    [level_one_1] => Array
        (
            [level_two_1] => value1
            [level_two_2] => valuetwo
            [level_two_3] => value_three
        )
    [level_one_2] => Array
        (
            [level_two_4] => value1
            [level_two_5] => valuetwo
            [level_two_6] => value_three
        )
    [level_one_3] => Array
        (
            [level_two_2] => valuetwo
            [level_two_3] => value_three
        )
)
```

Is it a quick way to covert it to something like this:

```
Array
(
    [level_one_1/level_two_1] => value1
    [level_one_1/level_two_2] => valuetwo
    [level_one_1/level_two_3] => value_three

    [level_one_2/level_two_4] => value1
    [level_one_2/level_two_5] => valuetwo
    [level_one_2/level_two_6] => value_three)

    [level_one_3/level_two_2] => valuetwo
    [level_one_3/level_two_3] => value_three
)
```

Slash between levels would be separator - it could anything. Also it would be dynamic numbers of levels.

Is it a way to do so by using predefined array* functions ? with recursion ?

Comment: Any reason you need to do this? Once you convert to the flat structure, you just make it that little bit harder to access anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Untested, but should help you get started in the right direction:

```
$myArray = array(
'level_one_1' => array(
        'level_two_1' => 'value1',
        'level_two_2' => 'valuetwo',
        'level_two_3' => 'value_three'
),
'level_one_2' => array(
        'level_two_4' => 'value1',
        'level_two_5' => 'valuetwo',
        'level_two_6' => 'value_three'
),
'level_one_3' => array(
        'level_two_2' => 'valuetwo',
        'level_two_3' => 'value_three'
));
$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($myArray));
$result = array();
foreach ($ritit as $leafValue) {
    $keys = array();
    foreach (range(0, $ritit->getDepth()) as $depth) {
        $keys[] = $ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->key();
    }
    $result[ join('/', $keys) ] = $leafValue;
}
```

Comment: Though, I do agree with Marc B. Flattening arrays can make it much harder to navigate your data.